# Locating image and text information

Tags: html, css

Iv'e been trying to locate an image in a center of a page, and to locate two text sections in it's sides (left and right). The right text section is locating under the image and I cant locate it in the same line.

here is my HTML code:

```
<pre>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="EXC.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="EXC.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ronimg">
            <img src="achivs.png"/>
            <br>
            <a href="EXC.html"><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span> GOBACK  </span></button></a>
        </div>
        <div id="ronalfor">
    THIS IS THE FIRST EXAMPLE


        </div>

                <div id="another">
    THIS IS THE SECOND EXAMPLE

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</pre>
```

This is the css code:

```
<pre>
#ronimg
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 600;
    clear: none;
}
#ronalfor
{
    color: #43acf8;
    font-style: oblique;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 5px inset #b1b53e;
    float:left;
    width: 500px

}

#another
{
    clear: both;
    color: #43acf8;
    font-style: oblique;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 5px inset #b1b53e;
    float:right;
    width: 500px
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue. I added a `flexbox` container around your HTML, implicitly making the children of the container into flex children. Then I use the `order` property to arrange the children the way you want (image in the middle with text sections flanking it).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;  
}

#ronimg img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#ronimg {
  order: 1; /* image in the middle */
}

#ronalfor,
#another {
  border: 5px inset #b1b53e;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #43acf8;
  flex-basis: 200px; /* sets a minimum width for these elements */
}

#ronalfor {
  order: 0; /* section on the left */
}

#another {
  order: 2; /* section on the right */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div id="ronimg">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <br>
    <a href="EXC.html">
      <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span> GOBACK  </span></button>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="ronalfor">
    THIS IS THE FIRST EXAMPLE
  </div>

  <div id="another">
    THIS IS THE SECOND EXAMPLE
  </div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxbyh2k5/)

Comment: thank you, but I still have a problem. Now I can put the image in the center and the sections in the sides, but the image takes the major place of the page and I have a tiny place in the sides to the text sections.

Comment: @user6539484 I changed the example code for you, removing the unnecessary floats. Notice how `#ronalfor` and `#another` have a `flex-basis: 200px;`. This means these side elements have a 200 pixel minimum width, while the other flex item, `#ronimg`, will take up the remaining space.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works! but i wil lappreciate if you will explain to me the meaning of the display:flex command and the order command

Comment: I know this is a lot to read, but it will fully educate you on flexbox and ordering: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#another { clear:both; }` that makes to locate it in same line.